# Вещественное деление двух чисел с помощью сопроцессора, затем вывод результата на экран. Компилятор TASM

Tags: ассемблер, числа-с-плавающей-точкой, tasm, деление

Уже несколько дней хочу научится орудовать вещественными числами, нужно для лабораторной. Даже нашёл алгоритм вывода на экран, понял его, и думал, что всё заработает. Программа принимает 2 числа, для примера x = 125, y = 4. z = x/y = 31.25. Но нет, выводит только 31.00. Другие числа, конечно, проверил. Помогите, пожалуйста, 2 дня потратил , сил нет. Уже думал реализовать деление в столбик)

```
DosSeg
include D:\tasm.2_0\tasm\io.asm
.model small
.stack 100
.data
inpX db "Enter X: ",'$'
inpY db "Enter Y: ",'$'
outZ db "Z = ",'$'
x   dd  ?
y   dd  ?
.code
.startup
.286C
mov ah, 9
lea dx, inpX
int 21h
inint ax                ; макрокоманда inint осуществляет ввод числа с клавиатуры
mov word ptr x, ax      

mov ah, 9
lea dx, inpY
int 21h
inint ax
mov word ptr y, ax      ; ввод y

mov ah, 9
lea dx, outZ
int 21h

push    bp              
mov     bp, sp
push    10              ; на 10 будем делить у умножать
push    0               ; ещё одно место под число

finit
fld y
fld x
fdiv st(0), st(1)       ; s(0) = s(0) / s(1) (

ftst                    ; сравнение s(0) с нулём
fstsw ax
sahf
jnc DROB                ; если > 0, то пропускаем вывод минуса
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, '-'
int 21h
fchs                    ; модуль числа
DROB:   ; пусть x = 125, y = 4, тогда:      31.25   8  ...
fld1    ; 1     31.25   
fld     st(1) ; 31.25   1   31.25   8   ...
fprem   ;остаток от деления на 1 в st(0) ; 0.25     1   31.25   8   ...
fsub    st(2), st(0)    ; целая часть в st(2)   0.25    1   31  8   ...
fxch    st(2)   ;теперь st - целая часть    ;    31     1   0.25    8   ...
xor cx, cx
CEL:
fidiv   word ptr [bp - 2]      ; делим целую часть на 10    3.1     1    0.25   ...
fxch    st(1)                  ;  1     3.1   0.25  ...
fld     st(1)                  ;  3.1   1     3.1   0.25 ...
fprem                          ;  0.1   1     3.1   0.25 ...
fsub    st(2), st              ;  0.1   1     3     0.25 ...
fimul   word ptr [bp - 2]      ;  1     1     3     0.25 ...
fistp   word ptr [bp - 4]      ;  1     3     0.25 ...
inc     cx
push    word ptr [bp - 4]      ; сохраним полученную цифру в стек
fxch    st(1)                  ; 3      1   0.25    ...
ftst                
fstsw   ax
sahf
jnz     short CEL              ; повторяем, пока st(0) != 0
mov ah, 02h
OUT1:
pop dx                          ; dx = 3,  dx = 1
add dl, 30h                     ; перевод в ASCII
int 21h
loop OUT1                       ; CX = количеству цифр в целой части
fstp    st(0)                  ;  1     0.25 ...
fxch    st(1)                  ;  0.25  1    ...
ftst        
fstsw   ax
sahf
jz      short CLEAR             ; если нет дробной части, то точку не ставить
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, '.'
int 21h
mov cx, 6                       ; максимум 6 знаков после запятой
DROB1:
fimul word ptr [bp - 2]     ; 2.5   1    ...
fxch st(1)                  ; 1.    2.5  ...
fld  st(1)                  ; 2.5   1    2.5    ...
fprem                       ; 0.5   1    2.5    ...
fsub    st(2), st           ; 0.5   1    2      ...
fxch    st(2)               ; 2     1    0.5    ...
fstp    [bp - 4]            ; 1     0.5     ...
mov     ah, 02h
mov     dl, [bp - 4]        ; [bp-4] = 2,       [bp-4] = 5
add     dl, 30h
int     21h
fxch    st(1)               ; 0.5 1
ftst
fstsw   ax
sahf
loopnz      short DROB1     ; повторять пока s(0) != 0 и cx != 0
CLEAR:
fstp st(0)                  
fstp st(0)
add sp, 4
pop bp

.exit   0
end
```

Comment: Как минимум стоит попробовать запустить под отладчиком и посмотреть какой реально результат получается. Потом от этого уже отталкиваться и разбираться на каком этапе что могло пойти не так.